# authentication forms login url and route data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

in my mvc4 asp.net project i have used simple membership, as you know in web.config you can specify the login url like below

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2880"  />
</authentication>
```

my problem is this, in projects urls i have a route data to determine culture info

sample url : http://somedomain.com/en-us/controller/action

assuming someone try to reach members only actions they will be redirected to url specified in web.config, i just want to know is there a way to change that url based on language route value?

sample > http://somedomain.com/en-us/controller/membersonly > redirect to >> http://somedomain.com/en-us/account/login

sample > http://somedomain.com/ku-ir/controller/membersonly > redirect to >> http://somedomain.com/ku-ir/account/login

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually i think i have found the answer!

the only think i need is a custom attribute inherited from `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` method

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
internal sealed class LocalizedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
        string language = filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] == null ? "en-us" : filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
        filterContext.Result = 
            new RedirectResult
                (string.Format("~/{0}/account/login?returnUrl={1}",
                                language,
                                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the main and pure Solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I had your same issue and you pointed me in the right direction.
I created a class in the filters Folder with this code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
internal sealed class LocalizedAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string language = filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] == null ? "en-us" : filterContext.RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
        filterContext.Result = 
        new RedirectResult
            (string.Format("~/{0}/account/login?returnUrl={1}",
                            language,
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery)));
         //base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }


}
```

Then from my controller i called it like this:

```
 [LocalizedAuthorize]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

It worked like a charm!
Thanks!

Comment: isn't that my own answer?!!

Comment: Hi Alejandro. Could edit your answer to make it clear how your code differs from the code in @user2675751's answer.  Thanks!

Comment: The code in the answer of Milad doesn't compile because it lacks the actual method definition. Instead the logic is directly in the class.
Also I like how Alejandro shows how to employ the attribute.

Comment: I think the best way is editing the @MiladHosseinpanahi answer rather create a new answer and add some parts. Anyway, Thanks for the pratic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot simply set a value in `loginUrl` that will change to the current culture.

I have a site where I have the culture in the URL and specify the `loginUrl`.

What I do is that in each request, I ensure that the culture is specified in the URL, if it is not, I simply redirect the user by prepending the culture to the current requested URL.

Therefore, /en-us/controller/memberonly -> /account/login -> /en-us/account/login

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the previous example, it helped me a lot. I just want to share your answer rewriten for vb.net

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class Or AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited:=True, AllowMultiple:=True)>
Class cAuthorizeAttribute

    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute

    Protected Overrides Sub HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
        Dim strLanguage As String = filterContext.RouteData.Values("lang")
        If Not strLanguage Is Nothing Then
            filterContext.Result = New RedirectResult(String.Format("~/{0}/Account/Login?returnUrl={1}", strLanguage, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery)))
        Else
            MyBase.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Little note, if you want to impact all your controlers, you should put this in the FilterConfig.vb

```
Public Shared Sub RegisterGlobalFilters(ByVal filters As GlobalFilterCollection)
    filters.Add(New HandleErrorAttribute())
    filters.Add(New cAuthorizeAttribute())
End Sub
```